Hypothetically, if one only has half an hour to pray the Yom Kippur evening service, what are the most important prayers to include?
I was wondering if there is prayers that are absolutely necessary to be said at the Yom Kippur evening service, (such as Kol Nidre, or Shema) if someone was in a situation where they had to do an abridged service. Of course, ideally one is able to go through the full service, but what are the prayers of highest priority to be said?

Kol Nidrei only takes about 10 minutes

I was referring to the whole erev Yom Kippur evening service including Slichot and Viddui, sorry for the confusion. I know the Kol Nidre prayer itself doesn't take that long to recite.

What kind of service do you mean? Without the singing and chazzanus, I think most people could say all the prayers in under an hour.

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Would it be clearer to replace Erev Yom Kippur service (in title and body) with Yom Kippur night service? To me, Erev YK refers to the time before sunset between 9th and 10th Tishrei, not after it. (I know the actual Kol Nidrei text should ideally be recited before sunset, but even so.) (@Harel13)

@shmosel I suppose my shul must be slow then! I will edit the question.

@Harel13 edited for that, thanks for the suggestion

Why was my comment deleted?

I'm not sure! it was a good suggestion.
